# Send multilingual emails notifications with Checkout Rules in Commerce module?

Tags: rules, commerce

I have an on-line store using the Drupal Commerce module. When the checkout is done the buyer get an **email notificatio**n. So far so good.

My problem is that the website is multilingual (english, french and spanish) then I need to send the **email notification** in the correct language.

**To accomplish with this I think of:**

1) creating 3 different rules, one for each language at: **admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules**.

2) Each rule would have a condition to compare the user current language and an action to send the email notification in the correct language

3) Then when checkout is done the correct rule should be fired to send an email in the appropriated language

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Commerce Email](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_email):

> - Adds a configuration page for the order email
> - Email content can be entered into textarea/wysiwyg (if available) form
> - Email content can also be set to be loaded from a template file: commerce-order-email.tpl.php
> - Allows the insertion of the order items into the email, token addition: [commerce-email:order-items]
> - Supports Commerce Shipping
> - **Allows different language versions of each email**
> - Optional administrator email

Comment: I will check the module. But not sure if I will install 3 modules to do this. This module require **Variable_email** and  **Htmlmail** modules.

Comment: You ask for other way, not for a better way ;-). In fact variable_email and htmlmail also have requirement : variable and mail_system.

Comment: commerce email works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) is a better alternative now. It allows messages to be translated, and sent using the current site language (with Rules)... so it won't be necessary to create 3 different rules. It requires message and message_notify so it is free from variable & htmlmail.